# Where to download gvim 8.0?

Tags: gvim

Tried google it, but I still can't figure our where to download gvim 8.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vim.org website lists downloads for all platforms including Windows, it can be downloaded from here [Gvim.](https://www.vim.org/download.php#pc)

It includes GUI and console versions, for 32 bit and 64 bit systems.